# Unable to get the "Install" option for the PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I am trying to make my website as PWA and got the ServiceWorker integrated into it.
The ServiceWorker is registered properly as I am able to see the "offline" capabilities.

The **problem** though is that I am unable to get the "**Install**" button for installing the PWA.

I have followed the instructions related to pwa-install package, but still it doesn't work.

I have also opened a Github issue for the same which has more details and screenshots:
https://github.com/pwa-builder/pwa-install/issues/355

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use Lighthouse tool in Chrome developer tools. Simpy navigate to Lighthouse tab then check "Progressive Web App". This will outline details on what you are missing.

[image]

You mentioned you already have a Service Worker. Now work on your Manifest file and redirect traffic to https (not http) as minimum requirements for your app to be installable.

In your website: https://www.kcak11.com/, As of this writing - 14 July 2020 9:33 pm (PST), The PWA configuration errors are as follows:

- The Manifest file has an error: display value is not one of:
  minimal-ui | fullscreen | standalone
- start_url does not respond with a 200 when offline. The start_url did
  respond, but not via a service worker
- Is not configured for a custom splash screen. Failures: Manifest does
  not have `background_color`

Lighthouse already provides some tips (via Learn More link) to fix these issues. Fix these issues and your PWA will be installable.

Below is a sample optimal result of a PWA Lighthouse report (using my PWA website):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I updated the 'display' property in manifest.json and I am able to see the "Install" now.