# Next-Pwa not working on production server such as Nginx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, next.js, progressive-web-apps

I am working based on Next.js example app like below link

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/progressive-web-app

and here is my `next.config.js`

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache')

module.exports = withPWA({
    pwa: {
        dest: 'public',
        register: true,
        runtimeCaching,
    }
})
```

and here is the `manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "nex-pwa",
  "short_name": "app",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "theme_color": "#3056de",
  "background_color": "#3056de",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "/icons/homescreen48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "/icons/homescreen72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "/icons/homescreen96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    }, {
      "src": "/icons/homescreen144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "splash_pages": null
}
```

and there is Nginx `server` file

```
server 
{
    root /var/www/domain.com/html/pwa;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    error_log /var/www/domain.com/html/pwa/log/error.log;

    location ~/images(.*$) { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035/images$1; 
        proxy_redirect off; 
    }

    location ~/fonts(.*$) { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035/fonts$1; 
        proxy_redirect off; 
    }

    location ~/icons(.*$) { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035/icons$1; 
        proxy_redirect off; 
    }

    location ~/sw.js(.*$) { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035/sw.js$1; 
        proxy_redirect off; 
    }

    location ~/workbox-c2b5e142.js(.*$) { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035/workbox-c2b5e142.js$1; 
        proxy_redirect off; 
    }

    location ~/_next(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035/_next$1;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

It is working on the development on local dev server but when I deploy to production like DigitalOcean with nginx it's not working anymore, I mean web app working but Installing Icon not showing on the browser.

What I have done wrong here, please.

Thanks

Comment: shouldn't that be `manifest.json`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes! It was a typing mistake.

Comment: I wonder if you've configured nginx correctly

Comment: Any network errors? is your sw.js file is exists and served?

Comment: @felixmosh yes it an error showing in the browser console but the web working fine . `workbox-c2b5e142.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"https://domain/css/animate.min.css","status":404}]
    at P (https:/domain/workbox-c2b5e142.js:1:11329)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async P.install (https://domain/workbox-c2b5e142.js:1:10742)`

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated my question and added my `server` file configuration. I am letting you know that in the production server web is working fin but the installing icon not showing but in development it's showing fine & working well.

Comment: @jesica check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62907206/unable-to-get-the-install-option-for-the-pwa/62907383#62907383

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this kind of error I was faced but I was overcome this stage & exactly sharing my configuration which working fine on my site with production server using Nginx.

Step 1: I am seeing your `manifest.json` file is okay.

Step 2: in the `next.config.js`

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')

module.exports = withPWA({
    pwa: {
        dest: 'public'
    }
})
```

and save & run/restart the development server like `npm run dev` then it will generate `sw.js` & `workbox-*.js` if these files are generated then again stop the development server & open the `next.config.js` update the file like below

```
module.exports = withPWA({
    pwa: {
        disable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
        // dest: 'public', // comment out this line
        register: true,
        sw: '/sw.js'
    }
})
```

Now project upload into the server & the Nginx server update but I am seeing the `server` file is fine just update this section based on your file

```
location ~/workbox-c2b5e142.js(.*$) {  // from public folder
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3035/workbox-c2b5e142.js$1; 
    proxy_redirect off; 
}
```

and restart the server & build the project & restart the `pm2` & that's it.

I think it will work.

Let me know if you have any confusion.

Thanks

Comment: Let me check and I will back to you soon. Thanks

Comment: Why do we comment out the public folder isn't the service worker supposed to live there?

Answer (score 0):

The console error  you mention in the comments mentions `/css/animate.min.css` and shows a 404 error for that file... Also your nginx config doesn't appear to have a `/css` rule. Maybe you need to add that, like:

```
server 
{
    root /var/www/domain.com/html/pwa;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    error_log /var/www/domain.com/html/pwa/log/error.log;

    location ~/css(.*$) { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035/css$1; 
        proxy_redirect off; 
    }

    # ... your other location rules
}
```

That said, I'm wondering why you are proxy passing each directory separately to the same destination. Why not just use `try_files` on the static directory instead and only proxy calls that the server/next actually needs to render. I'm guessing `localhost:3035` is your node/next server? You might try something like:

```
server 
{
    root /var/www/domain.com/html/pwa;

    server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

    error_log /var/www/domain.com/html/pwa/log/error.log;

    location / {
        root /var/www/domain.com/html/pwa/static;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3035;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

This assumes your static files generated by your build process are located in `/var/www/domain.com/html/pwa/static`, if not, adjust the `root` settings in `location /` to the root folder where your `image/`, `fonts/`, etc. actually are.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I have tried like this but didn't work. Same as before.